# Is there any After commit like hook for GORM: Golang?

Tags: go, go-gorm

I come from rails and am new to Golang.
Is there any way to have a after_commit callback for gorm, like we have for active record.

Answer (score 0):

There are no after-commit [hooks](https://gorm.io/docs/hooks.html) in GORM v2, but you can add them yourself as explained in [#1591](https://github.com/go-gorm/gorm/issues/1951):

> First define the callbacks, which will invoke your `AfterCreateCommit`
> func defined on your model struct:
>
> ```
> // afterCreateCommitCallback will invoke `AfterCreateCommit`, `AfterSaveCommit` method
> func afterCreateCommitCallback(scope *gorm.Scope) {
>   if !scope.HasError() {
>       scope.CallMethod("AfterCreateCommit")
>   }
>   if !scope.HasError() {
>       scope.CallMethod("AfterSaveCommit")
>   }
> }
>
> // afterUpdateCommitCallback will invoke `AfterUpdateCommit`, `AfterSaveCommit` method
> func afterUpdateCommitCallback(scope *gorm.Scope) {
>   if _, ok := scope.Get("gorm:update_column"); !ok {
>       if !scope.HasError() {
>           scope.CallMethod("AfterUpdateCommit")
>       }
>       if !scope.HasError() {
>           scope.CallMethod("AfterSaveCommit")
>       }
>   }
> }
>
> // afterDeleteCommitCallback will invoke `AfterDeleteCommit` method
> func afterDeleteCommitCallback(scope *gorm.Scope) {
>   if !scope.HasError() {
>       scope.CallMethod("AfterDeleteCommit")
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> Next, append those callbacks to your db.
>
> ```
> db, err := gorm.Open("postgres", credentials)
> if err != nil {
>   return err
> }
>
> db.LogMode(logEnable)
>
> db.Callback().Create().
>   After("gorm:commit_or_rollback_transaction").
>   Register("after_create_commit", afterCreateCommitCallback)
>
> db.Callback().Update().
>   After("gorm:commit_or_rollback_transaction").
>   Register("after_update_commit", afterUpdateCommitCallback)
>
> db.Callback().Delete().
>   After("gorm:commit_or_rollback_transaction").
>   Register("after_delete_commit", afterDeleteCommitCallback)
> ```
>
> This adds the callback after the event
> `gorm:commit_or_rollback_transaction` happens during the
> `Create`/`Update`/`Delete` call.