# GORM Post Transaction Commit Hook

Tags: go, orm, go-gorm

I am trying to get a hook Post transaction is committed in GORM, but it seems to support pre-transaction commit hooks only. [GORM Hooks](https://gorm.io/docs/hooks.html)

I found this answer on SO [Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70113632/is-there-any-after-commit-like-hook-for-gorm-golang)
This doesn't seem to work anymore as `gorm.Scope` is not exposed. How do you implement a callback Post transaction commit on a table is done?

Comment: There is no AfterCommit function on Callback(). Can you share any code reference from the form library itself?